# Matlab: Find a string pattern and replace it by a random string

Tags: regex, matlab

Consider the string:

```
str = 'text text [[i]] text text [[i]]'
```

The [[i]] string should be replaced by a random integer, say 1 for the first [[i]] and 5 for the second [[i]]. Is there a way to achieve this in Matlab without relying on the `split` command?

The classical

```
newstrreg = regexprep(str, '\[\[i\]\]',num2str(rand(1)))
```

will replace all [[i]] in the same string by the same randomized value, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a callback method [is not supported](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/279165-callback-execution-using-regular-expression) as a replacement argument. Do it in a loop replacing each match only `once`:

```matlab
str = 'text text [[i]] text text [[i]]'
for i = 1:2
  str = regexprep(str, '\[\[i\]\]',num2str(rand(1)), 'once');
end
```

Output:

```
str = text text 0.8329 text text 0.87961
```

Comment: And if the number of [[i]] instances is not known, how would you count them? Thanks

Comment: @pluton See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/count.html and https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#MATLAB_.2F_Octave

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with one regexprep call:

```
>> str = 'text text [[i]] text text [[i]]';
>> regexprep(str,'\[\[i\]\]','${string(rand)}')

ans =

    'text text 0.81472 text text 0.90579'
```